# PPTP VPN works from Windows, not Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn, pptp

I can't connect to my work's PPTP VPN from Linux. But when I reboot to Windows, it works.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I try to connect using Network Manager and PPTP plugin.

`nmap` returns the following opened port information about the VPN server:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
113/tcp  open   ident
443/tcp  open   https
1723/tcp closed pptp
```

As you can see, the port 1723 is closed. And indeed, if I try `telnet` (suggested by [pptp diagnostics docs](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#1723)): `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`.

So how is it possible Window connection works? And more importantly: how to make Linux works, so I won't have to reboot?

PPTPD log:

```
Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
nm-pptp-service-11960 log[main:pptp.c:350]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
nm-pptp-service-11960 warn[open_inetsock:pptp_callmgr.c:352]: connect: Connection refused
nm-pptp-service-11960 fatal[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:134]: Could not open control connection to xx.xx.xxx.x
nm-pptp-service-11960 fatal[open_callmgr:pptp.c:526]: Call manager exited with error 256
```

PPTP passthrough IS enabled on my router.

Answer (score 2):

Since it works on the same hardware running windows, it's likely the software firewall in ubuntu, or possibly upnp in windows configuring the router for the traffic (see last section of post).

As a brute force check, disable the firewall completely with this command:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

and see if you can then connect with the pptp connection. To turn it back on, replace disable with enable.

If it does work after you disable the firewall (ufw), then you need to configure the firewall to allow the traffic if you want to continue using it. If you are on a completely trusted network (home) behind a hardware firewall (your router), it may be overkill to be using a software firewall. It's your decision; opinions vary.

To use pptp with the firewall enabled:

These instructions worked in 14.x; I haven't tested them in 16.x; I'm not aware of any change in the firewall that would have changed this though.

As root, edit:

```
vi /etc/ufw/before.rules
```

just before the line # drop INVALID add the following:

```
-A ufw-before-input -p 47 -j ACCEPT
```

Save and close. 
Then in terminal

```
sudo ufw allow 1723/tcp
sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

If the firewall being disabled doesn't make a difference:

Check if the port to the vpn is open from a 3rd parties perspective. Go to this website http://www.canyouseeme.org/, and enter 1723 and - afterwards - 47, and the ip address (of the VPN server, not yours) to see if a route to these ports exists outside of your LAN.

It's possible that windows is using upnp to open a port in your router and enable GRE packets (port 47, a special packet type that pptp uses), which linux isn't doing. In that case, disabling the ubuntu firewall will make no difference, and the router will have to be manually configured to pass through GRE traffic and allow port 1723. Post your results.

### Update

Can you ping the VPN server?
What does traceroute 'vpnserver' show?

PPTP is typically the most difficult VPN protocol to configure in linux; do they offer an alternative like openvpn?

I would configure iptables to output verbose logs and see what is getting dropped. See http://linuxconfig.net/manual-howto/how-to-enable-iptables-log-file-in-ubuntu-11-04.html

Try each step that fails and post logs if you can.

Comment: The firewall has always been disabled. Forwarding GRE port seems like a good idea, but doesn't help. See the update for pptpd log.

Comment: Ping doesn't work (but the machine is up and running) and they don't offer other alternatives. I'll try to run `tshark` on my DD-WRT router, connect with Windows, and see what's going on.